# Backpack Date Range Picker doesn't not support 24H

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm using the date range picker and is not working with 24H mode, only in am/pm the locale attribute only allow to change de datetime format. Any way to use 24h format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with 24H format, you need to active "timePicker24Hour" in "date_range_options", like this example:

```
[ // Date_range
            'name'       => ['start_date', 'end_date'], // a unique name for this field
            'label'      => 'Date Range'.backpack_pro_badge(),
            'type'       => 'date_range',
            'default'    => ['2020-03-28 01:01', '2020-04-05 02:00'],
            // OPTIONALS
            'date_range_options' => [ // options sent to daterangepicker.js
                'timePicker' => true,
                'locale'     => ['format' => 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'],
                'timePicker24Hour' => true,
            ],
        ],
```

Cheers